# Stop click event from triggering another part of the same block

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla javascript, I have 2 language block, the first language block is used for dropdown and the second language block is used just inline EN/FR, we reuse the same language block in different parts of the site and we can't modify the structure since it would be complicate to do so.

For the second language block, if I want to go to FR, I need to click twice to go to FR page because it has open/close that originally assign for the first language block.

I add "open" class, so now it has open class, which I can click to the second page, however, when I click another part, ex: click text, window or just part of the body, it triggers the click second language block to be dropdown: open -> close -> open and so on.

My question, how I always have "open" class for the second language block? or basically I don't want to trigger the second language block to be open or close, but it remains just keep open so I can just click it once and it doesn't trigger open/close.

Below just some codes from the second language block, but for the first language block, I don't include it since it's not related to the issue, so far I tried:

```js
const modalLanguage = document.querySelector(".modal .language-option");
const modalSelectLanguage = document.querySelector(".modal .select_language");

if(modalLanguage){
    modalSelectLanguage.classList.add("open");
}
```

```css
.open{
display :block;
}

.hide{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
    <div class="language_toggle">
        <div class="select_language">
            <ul class="select_language__trigger">
                <li value="select_language">EN</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="language-option">
                <li>
                    <a href="/fr">FR</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to add more code, we can't reproduce the problem from what you've shown.

Comment: @Ivan86, but that's the main code, I just want to know if there's a way to keep class "open" or prevent the click event from the other blocks

Answer (score 0):

You should add more information and explain your problem in a more concise and understandable way. I think you can read this documentation that can help you fix your problem:

[Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Also, you talked about toggling open/close class, but in your JS snippet you don't check for the current class to do that toggle. It should be something like:

```
if(modalLanguage){
    let modalLanguageClassList = modalSelectLanguage.classList;
    modalLanguageClassList.includes('open') ? modalLanguageClassList.remove('open') : modalLanguageClassList.add("open");
}
```

And then you can just know that if it doesn't include open class, then it's close (no need for an extra close class, duplicating the same logic for the open class, just modified CSS)

Hope this helps!